# Wix: Add a sequential registry key

Tags: wix, registry, installation, wix3

I am writing an installer using Wix 3 which installs a plugin to a 3rd party application.  The application uses a group of registry keys to detect installed plugins. Each plugin is required to add a new subkey with a numerical name from 0-9 to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vendor\App\Plugins`.  The key contains a single string value which is the ProgId of a COM component which the application will instantiate.  So for example I would need to add the following key to install my plugin:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vendor\App\Plugins\0
  REG_SZ   ProgId    "MyCompany.MyPlugin"
```

However, if the `0` key already exits, my installer needs to be smart enough to create key `1` instead of `0` and on down through key 9.  Is there a way to achieve this using the Wix syntax?  I know I can write a custom action to do this, but if at all possible I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RegistrySearch to find the first empty value. But it would be easier to use the approach I describe at http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/07/01/semi-custom-actions/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was very slick and helpful.  Just one question, in the post the last parameter passed to `WcaAddTempRecord` is `wzComponent`.  Is this supposed to be the ID of a component already in my Wix files or should I use `WcaAddTempRecord` to add a new component to the component table specifically for my registry entry?  Thanks again!

Comment: It should be an existing component that controls whether the registry values are written.